# Possible to set a maximum of memory consumption on a powershell script in % or megabyte?

Tags: powershell, memory-management, scripting, out-of-memory, powershell-3.0

I sometimes have scripts which are eating up all the memory. Since I don't want to monitor them all the time or set cpu priority to low manually I am wondering if there is an option to give that specific script a value (maybe in mb) of memory.
Does this option exist?

Comment: What would you want to have happen when it reaches the limit. The reason it is reaching the limit is because the script needs to store information in memory to do what you wrote it to do. Would you want it to simply stop at the limit. That is about the only thing that some external process could do. If you want it to be more intelligent about the way it uses memory, you have to write that logic into the script.

Comment: i thought maybe there is a way to swap from memory to hdd or something?

Comment: The OS will automatically use a pagefile when it runs out of physical memory. Attempting to outsmart the OS's memory manager will not end well for you.

Comment: I would suggest looking at what you are trying to do in the script and find a way to either not hold so much in memory to begin with (i.e. filtering results from a search) or write your script so it stores the information in a file then processes discrete chunks of the data.

Comment: OK, my problem is that i have 13.300 folders which each have around 20 zip files in it. I need to delete the zip files which have not .txt file in it and keep the latest modified 2 files of each folder. any ideas how to manage that :) ?

Comment: I would capture all the eligible files (zip files but not latest two) with something like this `$zips = ls . -r -dir | %{ls $_.PSPath *.zip | sort lastwritetime -desc | select -skip 2} | % FullName`.  Then foreach over each zip path and use your code to determine if zip contains txt and delete those paths that don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't provide any built-in way to control system resources like the memory used by a script.

Windows does provide a way to limit system resources to groups of processes, you can learn more about that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx

If your scripts are consuming too much memory, I'd suggest investigating the memory leak.  There are many tools that help track memory leaks.  Some are low level (e.g. using !dumpheap from SOS in windbg - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx).  Others are pretty smart, letting you take multiple snapshots and show you just the newly allocated objects between the snapshots.  You can search for ".Net memory profiler" to get an idea of what's available.