# How to get Min/Max Memory Utilization of my system through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Hi everyone is there any Powershell command to find min/max memory utilization of my system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to set a maximum of memory consumption on a powershell script in % or megabyte?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861313/possible-to-set-a-maximum-of-memory-consumption-on-a-powershell-script-in-or-m)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [win32_operatingsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI object. You can get hold of it like this:

```
$os = gwmi win32_operatingsystem
```

It will tell you how much memory is available, and how much is now free, amongst other things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I my requirement is, what is minimum and maximum memory utilization of CPU?

Comment: @SushantNilajkar - you need to be a bit more specifc. Over what sort of timeframe do you need to know the utilization?

Comment: I need to know what will be minimum and maximum memory utilization out of the available total memory (RAM) of a system.